# Mineflayer Webpanel is not working, what can i do?

Tags: javascript, mineflayer

I am making a bot for my minecraft server and I'm trying to use a plugin called minefaler-webpanel, but whatever I do, it doesn't work.

I am currently using this for the plugin.

```
const webpanel = require('mineflayer-webpanel')

// other imports

const panel = webpanel(bot, {
  port : 8080
});

panel.listen(2345);
```

Can someone tell me how I can fix it?